# Применение LocalStorage для сохранения выбранного значения

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Возникает ошибка при изменение значения value, разметка:

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
</select>
```

js-код:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("fruit").onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('fruit', document.getElementById("fruit").value);
}

if (localStorage.getItem('fruit')) {
    document.getElementById("fruit").options[localStorage.getItem('fruit')].selected = true;
}
</script>
```

Все работает нормально, но при изменении value:

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="first">1</option>
    <option value="second">2</option>
    <option value="third">3</option>
    <option value="fourth">4</option>
</select>
```

Сохранение выбранных значений перестает работать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все потому что у вас значения `option value` идут по порядку (0,1,2...) - после вы их используете как индексы для доступа к элементам массива `getElementById("fruit").options`. Если вы поставите значения с 1 или перемешаете список `option`, уже будет нарушена подстановка прошлого выбранного элемента.

Вам требуется находить необходимый `option` исходя из его `value` значения, например так:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('fruit')) {
    let savedValue = localStorage.getItem('fruit');
    let option = document.querySelector('#fruit > option[value="' + savedValue + '"]');
    if (option) {
        option.selected = true;
    }
}
```

[Тестить](https://jsfiddle.net/Lahrpspd/)!

Для мульти селекторов предлагаю следущее решение (с использованием jQuery):

HTML (обязательно провайдните id и добавьте на требуемые селекторы класс `save-selector`):

```
<select id="fruit1" class="save-selector">
    <option value="first">1</option>
    <option value="second">2</option>
    <option value="third">3</option>
    <option value="fourth">4</option>
</select>

<select id="fruit2" class="save-selector">
    <option value="first">1</option>
    <option value="second">2</option>
    <option value="third">3</option>
    <option value="fourth">4</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('.save-selector').change(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('selector-' + this.id, this.value);
});

$('.save-selector').each(function() {
  let value = localStorage.getItem('selector-' + this.id);
  if (value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
});
```

Суть проста: подписываем все селекторы с классом `save-selector` на событие `change`, сохраняем каждого в локальное хранилище с префиксом `selector-`. Далее при загрузки страницы надо просто пройтись по всем селекторам с классом `save-selector` и пытаемся вытянуть из хранилища значение каждого.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,
в случае, если select-ов будет несколько fruit, fruit-1, fruit-2, fruit-3 стоит дублировать для каждого селекта этот код или можно как-то сократить его, или изменить поиск элемента не по id, а например по классу?

Comment: @Эмиль разрешено ли использовать jQuery?

Comment: да, если это хорошее решение))

Comment: @Эмиль обновил ответ.

Comment: geniusly, @AGS17